# NANT: nunit3-console.exe requires the --inprocess swtich on one enviroment but not another

Tags: nunit, nant

Using the following NANT script to execute an NUNIT test assembly (using nunit3-console.exe):

```
<target name="Test">
     <exec basedir="${nunit.base.dir}"
                   workingdir="${unittest.test}" 
                   program="nunit3-console.exe" 
                   commandline="Test.dll" 
      failonerror="true" />
</target>
```

works fine on one machine, but on a different machine using the exact same basedir path, workingdir path, and Test.dll assembly, results in the following exception thrown by the nunit console runner (3.4.1):

```
[exec] System.Exception: Unable to acquire remote process agent
[exec]    at NUnit.Engine.Runners.ProcessRunner.CreateAgentAndRunner()
[exec]    at NUnit.Engine.Runners.ProcessRunner.LoadPackage()
[exec]    at NUnit.Engine.Runners.AbstractTestRunner.Load()
[exec]    at NUnit.Engine.Runners.AggregatingTestRunner.LoadPackage()
[exec]    at NUnit.Engine.Runners.AbstractTestRunner.Load()
[exec]    at NUnit.Engine.Runners.MasterTestRunner.LoadPackage()
[exec]    at NUnit.Engine.TestEngine.GetRunner(TestPackage package)
[exec]    at NUnit.ConsoleRunner.ConsoleRunner.RunTests(TestPackage package
```

If I use the --inprocess switch it will resolve the immediate issue.  However, I need to use the --x86 swtich as well.  --inprocess and --x86 are not compatible.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are any of the paths on the second machine mapped network drives? .NET treats mapped network drives as low trust by default causing problems for NUnit. If that is the case, set the mapped drives to trusted by following https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/shawnfa/2004/12/30/using-caspol-to-fully-trust-a-share/

Comment: Yes, there was a mapped network drive.  I tried moving the filed to a local drive but I still encountered the same error.  Thanks for the suggestion though, it seemed promising!

Comment: Is the location NUnit is installed on a mapped drive? That is often the problem.

Comment: I tried it with all files located on the C drive, same error.